# Excel Pivot Table Auto sort

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, pivot-table

I have the following 3 tables that pull values from a larger table and I need the tables and also the charts to auto sort in ascending order once the master data changes. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKLRV.png)
I got table 1 to auto sort on update with the following VBA code but for some reason it does not work on tables 2 and 3. (Note that I have only changed the Column indeces in the code) and that does not help with the other tables [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVsq3.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("X:X")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("X4").Sort _
              Key1:=Range("X4"), _
              Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK:AK")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("AK4").Sort _ 
              Key1:=Range("AK4"), _
              Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AY:AY")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("AY4").Sort _
              Key1:=Range("AY4"), _
              Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions corrections are welcome

Comment: Just add the `if not intersect` code from the other two methods into the first one

Comment: That still just helps only on the first table

Comment: Why do you sort `OrderCustom:=1`. Do you really have a custom sorting list you want to use?

Comment: No idea, I just want to sort it in an ascending order and found a similar code that I adjusted to fit my workbook.What would it be in my case then ?

Answer (score 0):

First remove `On Error Resume Next`, it won't help you to discover problems by just ignoring/skipping past them. This is a poor habit that needs to be broken.

You cannot just create a new event procedure by naming it 2 and 3. Put all the necessary code in the single Change event. That is, there is only a single Change event per sheet.